# Merge conditional mapped types in typescript

Tags: typescript

We specify a type using mapped types using the following base interface

```js
interface A {
    a: string
    b: number
    c: number
}
```

If we index the mapped type with its own keys like this

```js
type B = {
    [K in keyof A]: {
        [K_ in K]: A[K_]
    }
}[keyof A]
```

It will produce a union of each key with its own type

```js
type B = {
    a: string;
} | {
    b: number;
} | {
    c: number;
}
```

If we use the method above, where we index a mapped type with its own keys, we can extract only some of that keys with their matching type, like in the following example

```js
type C = {
    [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends number ? {
        [K_ in K]: A[K_]
    } : never
}[keyof A]
```

Which will produce

```js
type C = {
    b: number;
} | {
    c: number;
}
```

#### Question

Is it possible to make the same conditional selection we have seen in `type C` and produce not a union but a full type like the following?

```js
type C = {
    b: number;
    c: number;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzHPAIyJAFcBbG6a3Be51qLAXyxYwATwAOKAMLIAvJjzyFipcoUB6VcgDqwADY7koqAHsAJgyQF2yANoBpZKGQBrCMKMw0AXSKo7n5BAAHpAgJsTIjCzQyAD8cvLqyCLiyFKyGMh0EdzQANzIfMgAPnKc2VFQ+QLKdgD6DiDItt5odZ5WhfQQAG7RKv0DCRqaKADucOBE-NYubh6o-oNLg4nJkjJyWZE8+WXbeQWCWEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to drop all unmatched keys by remapping them to `never`:

```js
type C = {
    [K in keyof A as A[K] extends number ? K : never]: A[K]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clean solution. I made a new question, based on your answer. Maybe you'll [want to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73380727/exclude-from-conditional-mapped-type-in-typescript) :)