# Exclude `{}` from conditional mapped type

Tags: typescript, typescript4.0

We work on the following interface

```js
interface A {
    a: string
    b: string
    c?: number
    d?: number
}
```

And we have a type which makes every key in `T` **optional** if their type is `string` and **required** if it is `number`

```js
type B<T> = {                                      
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (number|undefined) ? K : never]-?: T[K]                      
} & {
    [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (string|undefined) ? K : never]+?: T[K] 
}

/* The resulting type will be:
type B<A> = {
    c: number;
    d: number;
} & {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
}
*/
```

However, if we change the interface we are working on to only include one of the types specified in the condition, `{}`, which *almost* corresponds to `any` will be added to the resulting type

```js
interface A1 {
    a: string
    b: string
}

/* The resulting type will be:
type B<A1> = {} & {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
}
*/
```

This will allow assigning many unwanted types to B, defeating out purpose. For example

```js
const b: B<A1> = "We don't want this to happen." // <-- We need an error here.
```

#### Question

How to prevent the resulting type from including `{}` ? I want `B<A1>` to result in the following type

```js
{
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
}
```

#### Playground Link

I have simplified the type by removing the generic, so that resulting types are visible. You can check it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzHPAIyNPJCr2QQH4iQBXAWxumq4AJh2Tc+AgL5YsYAJ4AHFACFkAXkwst2nbt2DkAbQDSyUMgDWEOQHsYafMTQmAusggAPSCCFOAFOL8UMgAPshcPhAwoBBCAJTIbMimnBAAbtAuALSiqK56BXhYksgAZJgGJmYgltZ2DnBOecZunt6+yH4MlKHhkdEgsQlJKWLpmQDUufnFWAD0AFTIAEoQxFwANmA98koEsooq6hUsCJy8QQDcBkLnElDXJeXYLHCi3Uy9EUJRMULXLBo7zIPTC31+g3+swWcxkCBsIFI+CIqg0GGQczmyAAPFkssgAPIWAA0yDAAAtgE4qcgAO7kuBgOkoWlwcCxAB0BkIyAARHBecSDJi6HyaIKDGdkAAGIUsW7IACMsywoEgsEQKFQipOeB5H2YtHoIKYKt2KAAwsd0YVbXbkJVTOYrLZ7NrHGhFfk2hAfP5AtAvv0-sNkshUhkoNlcl6Wvb9E9dbgqs66m6dY1Pd6vL6Ol0TRQgz8BkNEmGI5MYzNpIsVmtNttPub9ubkFa0YmXnrgYxC2Dg5CAbQe6C+sW-o8cDC4QikaL23yACqUpwGkjkmybIRiGxM-iOYjACggOA0DYoMA2ZDKACEvIxWNx+IA6ighAiAORM1ngMkrrkyFgQA)

Comment: There are some issues in the GitHub tracker involving intersections with empty objects, but I didn't find this specific issue. A workaround, try this helper (which ironically involves intersecting with an empty object): `type Expand<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };`

Comment: Thank you. It'd have been a hard time finding this fix by myself. Should I open an issue on this or is it expected behaviour? I think that you could post an answer with this workaround, maybe explaining why it works.

Comment: I'd very surprised that this is not already reported (the community is very active reporting this kind of thing), but you can try, if you don't find it. Btw, this should also work: `type Expand2<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };`. It looks like a bug to me, if you paste the type `C` and use it, then it works, this makes no sense to me.

Comment: It in fact [works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIEZkG8BQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOZ4EBGJ5lINAvjjmAJ4AOKAogA8ecEABMAPABUAfMgC82ZAG0A0slDIA1hC4B7GMikBdElLXHk7TrxQBhBciEjxErAQ+ev3n59r41DRBtXQM0TDhScItkCEFIcSiAChAAVwBbOmhkAB9kVPEIGFAIMQBKZAB+ZHUSEAgAN2hjAFpKkgwY3278HFZkADJsfxV1TR19QwxCKM7VSziEsWSmalz8wuL68qqa5DrG5oBqduj55D6ZHAB6ACpkACUIUlSAGzA17j4iGz5kB0UuA8cFOqxY6wKYiKJTEAG4RnRQRQ1nlIdDtvD2MhbtcOAg9CByMgGP9HAAiKQAC2AUTBVDIlL0bzEyBAejAxJQkVIwCoIDgdFeKDAemQACEAIRk5DXa7IABSqSJr2AOmQAHcUOrRJAxBKOBwgA). Should you post an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @soffyo I think this is the underlying issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42864. If you make a `type D = {[K in never]: any} & {a?: string | undefined, b?: string | undefined}`, you'll see that it also shows as `{} & {...}` and exhibits the same behavior as `C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Aplet123 points to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42864 as the root of the problem. A workaround (probably there are others even simpler): a helper that forces it to be an object type:

```
type Obj<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

const b: Obj<B<A1>> = "We don't want this to happen." // Error! Good.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to solve your problem.
By mapping over the object type C the empty object disappears, because it doesn't have any keys to map over to.[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=56&ssc=67&pln=35&pc=1#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-HNIUj8fkJVTF26r2dY00Ir8pmRwELj6wf0-sNknPBiXsrk7y0T30J5dVwTsam7eptUcW972HDouhNCgvjfSEP1Gb9Jj-GZJETeYllWdYth2Q59i3Xc0WA9tcDeY1GCQ18fgGWJV1wIFaNBPpGL+R4cBhOEESRUVyL5AAVSknE9YhyRsTYhDEGwmX4RxiH9EA4FdFAwBsZBlAAQl5DEsWgJ0oBkGQgA)

```
export type Narrow<A> =
  | (A extends Narrowable ? A : never)
  | (A extends [] ? [] : never)
  | {
      [K in keyof A]: A[K] extends Function ? A[K] : Narrow<A[K]>;
    };


type C =Narrow< {                                      
    [K in keyof A1 as A1[K] extends (number | undefined) ? K : never]-?: A1[K]                      
} & {
    [K in keyof A1 as A1[K] extends (string | undefined) ? K : never]+?: A1[K] 
}>
/* Resulting type:
type C = {
    a?: string | undefined;
    b?: string | undefined;
}
 */

const b: C = "This string should not be assignable to B!" // error
```

Comment: this works, but i think that [@tokland's suggested workaround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIEZkG8BQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOZ4EBGJ5lINAvjjmAJ4AOKAogA8ecEABMAPABUAfMgC82ZAG0A0slDIA1hC4B7GMikBdElLXHk7TrxQBhBciEjxErAQ+ev3n59r41DRBtXQM0TDhScItkCEFIcSiAChAAVwBbOmhkAB9kVPEIGFAIMQBKZAB+ZHUSEAgAN2hjAFpKkgwY3278HFZkADJsfxV1TR19QwxCKM7VSziEsWSmalz8wuL68qqa5DrG5oBqduj55D6ZHAB6ACpkACUIUlSAGzA17j4iGz5kB0UuA8cFOqxY6wKYiKJTEAG4RnRQRQ1nlIdDtvD2MhbtcOAg9CByMgGP9HAAiKQAC2AUTBVDIlL0bzEyBAejAxJQkVIwCoIDgdFeKDAemQACEAIRk5DXa7IABSqSJr2AOmQAHcUOrRJAxBKOBwgA) is all that is needed to solve this